How to show closed captioning in Exoplayer in Android?
I am following the below code to setup the Exoplayer and configure closed captioning, but the subtitles are never shown on the player view (androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The video format used is Mp4 and subtitle format is VTT.
val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(C.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .setContentType(C.AUDIO_CONTENT_TYPE_MOVIE)
        .build()
    val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(context)
    trackSelector.parameters = DefaultTrackSelector.Parameters.Builder(context).setRendererDisabled(C.TRACK_TYPE_VIDEO, false).build()

    val titleUri =
        Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + com.example.exoplayer.R.raw.sample_video_subtitle)
    val videoUri =
        Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + com.example.exoplayer.R.raw.sample_video)
    val subtitle =
        MediaItem.SubtitleConfiguration.Builder(titleUri) //subtitleUri
            .setMimeType(MimeTypes.TEXT_VTT) // The correct MIME type (required).
            .setLanguage("en") // The subtitle language (optional).
            .setSelectionFlags(C.SELECTION_FLAG_DEFAULT) // Selection flags for the track (optional).
            .build()
    val mediaItem =
        MediaItem.Builder().setUri(videoUri).setSubtitleConfigurations(mutableListOf(subtitle)).build()
    val defaultMediaSourceFactory= DefaultMediaSourceFactory(context)


    val exoPlayer = remember(context) {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .setMediaSourceFactory(dataMediaSourceFactory)
            .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
            .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes, true)
            .setHandleAudioBecomingNoisy(true)
            .build()
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        exoPlayer.setMediaSource(defaultMediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(mediaItem))
            exoPlayer.prepare()
            exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
    }

